# How to make cpu utilization only till 80%?

Tags: command-line

Currently I am using below command

```
stress -c 2 -i 1 -m 1
```

Question: with above command, cpu utilization goes till 100%. Is there anyway I can limit it to only 80%?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cpulimit` [link](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-limit-cpu-usage-of-a-process-with-cpulimit-debian-ubuntu) to limit CPU usage. Install `cpulimit` using below command.

`sudo apt install cpulimit`

Run stress command.

`stress -c 2 -i 1 -m 1`

Check `stress` PID using `ps`

`ps -ef | grep stress`

```
dedunu   14821 13536  0 14:56 pts/15   00:00:00 stress -c 1 -i 1 -m 1
dedunu   14822 14821 34 14:56 pts/15   00:06:29 stress -c 1 -i 1 -m 1
dedunu   14823 14821 37 14:56 pts/15   00:07:07 stress -c 1 -i 1 -m 1
dedunu   14824 14821 40 14:56 pts/15   00:07:39 stress -c 1 -i 1 -m 1
```

You can see PIDs of the stress command. Run cpulimit command for each and every stress process.

```
sudo cpulimit -p 14821 -l 80
sudo cpulimit -p 14822 -l 80
sudo cpulimit -p 14823 -l 80
sudo cpulimit -p 14824 -l 80
```